# „Für folgende Stelle“ oder „für diese Stelle“?

Tags: word-usage

Ich will einer Firma meine Bewerbung als Softwareentwickler per E-Mail schicken. Die Anzeige habe ich online gefunden. Ist die Formulierung folgendes Satzes in der E-Mail richtig?

> Im Anhang finden Sie meine Bewerbung als Softwareentwickler für folgende Stelle:
>   www.abcd.com/softwareentwickler
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen,
>   Mustermann

Comment: Ich würde keine der beiden Formulierungen wählen; schließlich ist eine URL keine Stelle, sondern nur ein Verweis auf eine Stellenausschreibung.

Comment: Die Grußformel „Mit freundlichen Grüßen“ steht ohne Komma.

Comment: @Loong, Quelle?

Comment: @CarstenS Siehe z. B. § 68(3) im amtlichen Regelwerk, Duden Band 1 (je nach Ausgabe etwa im Abschnitt „Gestaltung von Geschäftsbriefen“ oder „Maschinenschreiben und E-Mails“), Duden Band 9 (unter dem Stichwort „Brief“), Duden _Briefe gut und richtig schreiben!_ oder Duden _Professionelles Bewerben – leicht gemacht_.

Comment: @Loong, Danke. (Und wenn ich aus Platzgründen den Namen in der gleichen Zeile habe? Nun, da müsste ich wohl eine Frage stellen ;)

Comment: @CarstenS Interessante Frage! Dieser Fall wäre allerdings unglücklich, da bei einem normgerechten Geschäftsbrief der Name nicht nur in einer neuen Zeile an der Fluchtlinie beginnt, sondern auch noch mit einer Leerzeile vom Gruß abgesetzt wird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Eigentliche Antwort

Es ist beides richtig, ich persönlich würde jedoch eher zu `folgende` tendieren, da die Stellenbeschreibung danach erst folgt. Wenn man die Stellenbeschreibung davor setzt, würde ich `diese` verwenden.

Beispiel:

> Da Sie zurzeit auf LINK nach einem Softwareentwickler suchen, würde ich mich gerne auf diese Stelle bewerben. Meine Unterlagen befinden sich im Anhang.

## Allerdings

Normalerweise würde ich nicht auf die Quelle verweisen, wo ich die Stelle gefunden habe. Diese Information ist meistens nicht sehr hilfreich für die Firma, da die Personalabteilung eigentlich wissen sollte, welche Stellen ausgeschrieben sind.

Wenn die Firma mehrere Stellen als Softwareentwickler ausschreibt und diese verschiedene Zusätze haben, würde ich die komplette Beschreibung nehmen. Also beispielsweise `Softwareentwickler für ERP-Systeme`, `Spieleentwickler` oder `Webentwickler`.

Zudem würde ich selbst noch etwas mehr in die E-Mail schreiben. Zum Beispiel so etwas:

> Sehr geehrte/r/s Herr/Frau/Team X,
>
> da Sie zurzeit einen Kandidaten für die Stelle XY suchen, würde ich mich gerne dafür bewerben. Meine vollständige Bewerbung befindet sich im Anhang. Falls ich doch etwas vergessen haben sollte, können Sie mich auf folgenden Wegen erreichen:
>
> - E-Mail
> - Telefon
> - Adresse
>
> Mit freundlichen Grüßen
>
> Max Mustermann

Falls man unbedingt will, kann man den Link für die Ausschreibung noch in den ersten Teilsatz einfügen, zum Beispiel so:

> da Sie zurzeit einen Kandidaten für die Stelle XY suchen (LINK), …

Comment: "da die Personalabteilung eigentlich wissen sollte, welche Stellen ausgeschrieben sind" - ob du da mal nicht zu viel erwartest ... in der Tat haben aber zumindest im Bereich der Softwareentwicklung Stellen oft ID-Codes irgendeiner Form, die eine eindeutige Zuordnung erlauben sollten. Ich sehe aber trotzdem keinen Grund, hinter den Code nicht zusätzlich noch die Quelle in Klammern zu schreiben, denn blindlings darauf vertrauen, dass der richtige Code in der richtigen Anzeige gelandet ist und nicht aus einer Vorlage per Copy-und-Paste unabsichtlich übernommen wurde, würde ich generell nicht.